# Row expansion component submitting form on expansion when roweditor is present

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

My web page looks like this:

```
<h:form>

<p:dataTable var="car" value="#{tableBean.carsSmall}">

    <f:facet name="header">
         Expand rows to see detailed information
    </f:facet>

    <p:column style="width:16px">
        <p:rowToggler />
    </p:column>

    <p:column style="width:250px">
        <f:facet name="header">
                Model
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{car.model}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column style="width:250px">
        <f:facet name="header">
                Year
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{car.year}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:rowExpansion>
    <p:fieldset legend="Detail">
    <p:dataTable value="#{car.colors}" var="color">
        <p:column>
            <p:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="output">
                <h:outputText value="#{color.disable}" />
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input">
                <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{color.disable}" />
                </f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Edit">
            <p:rowEditor />
        </p:column>

    </p:dataTable>
     </p:fieldset>
    </p:rowExpansion>
</p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

This component is automatically updating the wrong values in database, for example it is setting false for the color.disable property upon just expanding the row.

I am using:

JSF 2.0.9
Primefaces 2.2.1

Comment: please provide your code, so that problem can be identified

Comment: rags , i have modified the question and provided the code.Let me know, if you need anything